# How to catch scrapy response from spider to pipeline?

Tags: python, django, scrapy, pipeline

I need all the scrapy response with settings, pipelines, urls and everything in pipeline where i create model objects? Is there any way of catching it?

```
pipeline.py


class ScraperPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        logger = get_task_logger("logs")
        logger.info("Pipeline activated.")
        id = item['id'][0]
        user= item['user'][0]
        text = item['text'][0]
        Mail.objects.create(user=User.objects.get_or_create(
            id=id, user=user),
            text=text, date=today)
        logger.info(f"Pipeline disacvtivated")
```

```
spider.py
class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['xxx.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'xxx.com',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                                 headers={'User-Agent':
                                              'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                                              'like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MailItem()
        for row in response.xpath('xpath thins'):
            ip['id'] = row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first(),
            ip['user'] = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first(),
            ip['text'] = row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(),
            yield item
```

I've tried to call response from pipeline, but i have only item. Also the things from created object are not enough from me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the full response along with the item in your callback methods if you need access to the response or request in your pipeline.

For example:

```
class SpiderClass(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.xpath(...):
            field1 = ...
            yield {'field1': field1, 'response': response}
```

Then in your pipeline you will have access to the response as a field of the item in the `process_item` method.  You can also access the settings from this method by using the crawler attribute of the spider argument.

For example:

```
class MyPipeline:

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        response = item['response']
        request = response.request
        settings = spider.crawler.settings
        ...   do something 
        del item['response']
        return item
```

Then you just need to activate the pipeline in your settings.